# How to encode a video with MediaCodec and H.265 (HEVC) in Android

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, hevc

There is some devices like Huawei Mate 9 and Nexus 6p that have hardware for HEVC encoding/decoding.

I'm tryint to change this class [BigFlake - CameraToMpegTest](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt) to encode using MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_HEVC video mine type. But I have no success.

First this is the issue:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Media format provided is neither AVC nor
>   AAC

What kind of special settings I need to provide to make it works?

Comment: you forgot to specify in which operation/line the exception was thrown

Comment: I realized that MediaMuxer is not compatible with HEVC media format. If we want to encode a H.265 mp4 video with MediaCodec, we need to use ffmpeg for muxing [hard work]. See more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.html